# Filter list by generic type

Tags: java, generics

I want to filter a list by a generic type. I have the `resource` of which I want to extract all elements of the generic type T like so:

```
class ListFilter<T> {
    Resource resource;
    ArrayList<T> filteredElements

    public ListFilter(Resource resource) {
        this.resource = resource;
        TreeIterator<EObject> it = resource.getAllContents();
        filteredElements = new ArrayList<>();
        while(it.hasNext()) {
            EObject nextElement = it.next();
            if (nextElement instanceof T) {  //This is where the error occurs
                elements.add((T) nextElement);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following error on the commented line:

> Cannot perform instanceof check against type parameter T. Use its
>   erasure Object instead since further generic type information will be
>   erased at runtime

How can I filter `resources` by the generic type T and save the elements into the 
`filteredElements` list? I prefer a solution without the use of other libraries.

Comment: This is not possible, see the DUP question I pointed you to. The thing is that this "T" is a compile-time thing; you can't make use of it at runtime the way you imagine.

Comment: I've never seen a `Resource` object... is some library providing it?

Comment: Yes, it is from the Ecore package